# struct and destructor

Tags: c#

I created the type `IntPtr<T>` to act like a generic pointer that c/c++ have:

```
public struct IntPtr<T> : IDisposable where T : struct
{
    private static Dictionary<IntPtr, GCHandle> handles = new Dictionary<IntPtr, GCHandle>();

    private IntPtr ptr;

    public IntPtr(ref T value)
    {
        GCHandle gc = GCHandle.Alloc(value, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        ptr = gc.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        handles.Add(ptr, gc);
    }

    public IntPtr(ref T[] value)
    {
        GCHandle gc = GCHandle.Alloc(value, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        ptr = gc.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        handles.Add(ptr, gc);
    }

    public IntPtr(IntPtr value)
    { ptr = value; }

    public IntPtr(IntPtr<T> value)
    { ptr = value.ptr; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (handles.ContainsKey(ptr))
        {
            GCHandle gc = handles[ptr];
            gc.Free();
            handles.Remove(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    public T? this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero) return null;
            if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            if (handles.ContainsKey(ptr))
            {
                GCHandle gc = handles[ptr];

                if (gc.Target is Array) return ((T[])gc.Target)[index];

                return (T)gc.Target;
            }

            return null;

        }
        set
        {
            if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            // not yet implemented
        }
    }

    private T[] getArray()
    {
        if (handles.ContainsKey(ptr)) return (T[])handles[ptr].Target;

        return null;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            if(handles.ContainsKey(ptr))
            {
                GCHandle gc = handles[ptr];
                if (gc.Target is Array) return ((T[])gc.Target).Length;

                return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator IntPtr(IntPtr<T> value) { return value.ptr; }

    public static implicit operator T(IntPtr<T> value) { return (T)value[0]; }

    public static implicit operator T[](IntPtr<T> value) { return value.getArray(); ; }

    public static implicit operator T?(IntPtr<T> value) { return value[0]; }

}
```

It's not complete yet but for now it works, the problem is i keep track of `GCHandle` by storing them in `handles` now i need to free the `GCHandle` once it no more needed so i have to declare a `destrcutor` but c# don't allow `struct` to have `destrcutor` or to override 'Finalize' method and if the such variable of type `IntPtr<T>` goes out of scope the destruction take place but the `GCHandle` won't be free.

**UPDATE**

As an example of this class usage, suppose we going to interpo `COAUTHIDENTITY` and `COAUTHINFO` from `COM`, here what it will look like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct COAUTHIDENTITY
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string User;
    uint UserLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Domain;
    uint DomainLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Password;
    uint PasswordLength;
    uint Flags;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct COAUTHINFO
{
    uint dwAuthnSvc;
    uint dwAuthzSvc;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszServerPrincName;
    uint dwAuthnLevel;
    uint dwImpersonationLevel;
    IntPtr<COAUTHIDENTITY> pAuthIdentityData;
    uint dwCapabilities;
}
```

Instead to make `pAuthIdentityData` an `IntPtr` and use `Marshal` member functions to get object of type `COAUTHIDENTITY`, `IntPtr<T>` will make it more simple.

The question is: where should i write the code to free `GCHandle` when the `IntPtr<T>` is released?

Comment: Just... why? what is it that you are trying to do here? Since you have limited `T : struct`, you already have scope-based lifetime on the value...? Or if it *was* a class, then assuming (from the usage here) that it is short-lived, it will be collected in generation zero *anyway*, which is very cheap.

Comment: Hmm... Is this class supposed to be an analogue to IntPtr but typesafe? IntPtr doesn't keep track of lifetime, it's just a pointer like a C pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reinventing the wheel. Look at the [SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) class. Use an existing descendant or create your own descendant.

Comment: SafeHandle is an operating system handle not a pointer to any data.

Comment: @Muhammad: Good point. You may want to look at [The Truth About GCHandles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clyon/archive/2005/03/18/398795.aspx) regarding the risks of GCHandles and boxing.